# Wordpress multiple pages on one page via button switching

Tags: plugins, tabs

Does anyone know if there is a Wordpress plugin for the following:

Let's say we have a page with certain information, for instance details about a product. I could make a link to another page with details about the pricing for that product, but I would like to have this accessible from the first page via a switchable button.

I'd like a two part button (tabs?) on the top of the page. Clicking part/tab A would show product details, clicking part/tab B would show the pricing information.

I think I have seen this implementation before, but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery tabs because they look slick and it's your best bet to keep up with all the various browser idiosyncrasies.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: However, Matt Cutts admits there is a "hidden text" penalty now.  If you care about SEO, do some research on this.  This has people with tabbed product pages freaked out and (as far as I know) Matt is not very specific about how much info in "hidden" tab is too much.  So if you have a lot of information per tab and you care about SEO, consider avoiding javascript-based tabs and make a totally new URL for each tab.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create tabs on your own the this article http://michaelwender.com/2010/11/01/creating-wordpress-shortcodes-for-jquery-tools-tabs/ is a great place to start

and if you want you can use one of these plugins:

- [WordPress Post Tabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-post-tabs/)
- [postTabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posttabs/)
- [cTabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ctabs/)
- [niceTabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nicetabs/)

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 0):

@EAMann, my appologies. I was in a hurry that time.
Here is a more elaborate answer:

@Joop, if I understand the question correctly you are not looking for a tabs-plugin per se, but for a way to add content of other pages to your tabs. This can be done using the [Improved Include Page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/improved-include-page/)  plugin. This plugin adds the content of another page into the page of your choice.
Example:
`[include-page id="123"]`.
You might be able to combine this with the earlier mentioned [Wordpress Post Tabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-post-tabs/) plugin (or another one):
`[tab name="Specifications"][include-page id="123"][/tab][tab name="Pricing Information"][include-page id="456"][/tab][end_tabset]`